# Groups with no perfect subgroups -- terminology?

Tags: gr.group-theory, terminology

Finite groups are solvable if they have no nontrivial perfect subgroup.  But I am sure that for infinite groups, the  two notions diverge.  Is there standard terminology for groups with no perfect subgroups?

Comment: Every subgroup of a free group is free, in particular non-perfect.  But it certainly isn't nilpotent.  So, yes, the two notions do indeed diverge.

Comment: When you say "nilpotent" do you mean "solvable"?  The group of permutations of three objects is not nilpotent, but it has no perfect subgroups (unless you count the trivial subgroup).

Comment: thanks:  changed nilpotent to solvable.  (and of course I don't count the trivial subgroup).

Comment: I don't know a name for it, but one way to think about the property in question is the following: Recursively define subgroups $G_\lambda\subset G$ for ordinals $\lambda$ by: $G_0=G$, and $G_{n+1}=DG_n$, and for a limit ordinal $\lambda$ take the intersection of what you have so far. By definition $G$ is solvable if $G_n=1$ for some natural number $n$. $G$ has no nontrivial perfect subgroup if $G_\lambda=1$ for some $\lambda$. In fact, I suppose this construction shows that every group has a unique maximal perfect subgroup, namely the first $G_\lambda$ such that $G_{\lambda+1}=G_\lambda$.

Comment: @Tom: The groups with $G_\lambda=1$ are called hypoabelian. See, for example, Vovsi, S. M.
Two notes on local properties of groups.
Simon Stevin 55 (1981), no. 1-2, 27–35. Also: http://planetmath.org/?op=getobj&from=objects&name=DescendingSeries

Comment: So that answers the question.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie the maximal perfect subgroup ("perfect radical"?) exists with no need to define this transfinite derived series. Namely it is the subgroup generated by all perfect subgroups.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the infinite case, there is a close notion of "locally indicable group", i.e. a group where every finitely generated subgroup maps onto $\mathbb Z$ (see, for example, [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2699673)). Locally indicable groups are left (right) orderable, hence important. Note that in that notion, not all subgroups are considered but only finitely generated, and "non-perfect" is replaced by a stronger property "maps onto $\mathbb Z$". But in the finite case all subgroups are finitely generated, and "maps onto $\mathbb Z$" is an infinite analog of "maps onto a finite cyclic group" (= non-perfect).  So "locally indicable" is possibly the infinite analog of the property you consider.

Update: The groups without perfect subgroups are called hypoabelian. See  [this text.](https://planetmath.org/descendingseries)